# Find the length of a segment in a trapezium

Tags: geometry

$ABCD$ is a trapezium where $AB$ is parellel to $CD$. $E$ is a point on side $AD$ and $F$ is a point on side $BC$ and $EF$ is also parallel to $CD$. If $EF$ divides $AD$ in the ratio $3:4$ then find out $EF$.

I am trying but do not know where to begin.

I would appreciate your effort.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't length of $AB$ and $CD$ given? Or something else maybe?

Comment: If you mean $AE/ED=3/4$, then $EF=(4 AB+3 CD)/7$.

Comment: @almagest that is what i want to know...how???? i need proof

Comment: If $AB=CD$, then $AD,BC$ are parallel and it is obvious that $EF=AB=CD$. If not, then let the lines $AD,BC$ meet at $O$. Now the triangles $OAB,OEF,ODC$ are similar.

Comment: @almagest: Sounds to me like your comments would make a fine answer.